# Run M-file in Google Colab but got error: no such file

Tags: google-colaboratory, octave

I want to run M-file (Octave) in Colab. first, I upload all file in Google Drive with the following address:
`/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/Corroded/hybrid/FAEICA_ANN/`

Then I used the following code to run my file:

```py
!apt install octave
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import sys
import os
py_file_location = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/Corroded/hybrid/FAEICA_ANN"
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(py_file_location))
!octave -W  MainANN_FAEICA.m
```

But I got:

> error: no such file, '/content/MainANN_FAEICA.m'
> error: source: error sourcing file '/content/MainANN_FAEICA.m'

Although I added the path, Colab cannot recognize the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added the directory to Python's system search path, not to Octave's search path.

The simplest way to run this file is to change the working directory to where the file is, then run the file:

```py
os.chdir(py_file_location)
!octave -W  MainANN_FAEICA.m
```

Comment: I use Google Colab.

Comment: @mohammad24 I don’t know what that matters. Did you try this? Did it not work? Please share any error messages you got.

Comment: Yes I tried it. I got: warning: Functions for spreadsheet style I/O (.xls .xlsx .sxc .ods .dbf .wk1
etc.)  are provided in the io package.  See <http://octave.sf.net/io/>.

Please read <http://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
error: 'xlsread' undefined near line 13 column 8
error: called from
    MainANN_FAEICA at line 13 column 6

Comment: @mohammad24 OK, so that means your script is running, and issue you posted about is solved. Your new issue is that `xlsread` in Octave require installing and loading the io package.

Comment: How should I install xlsread for Octave and loading the io package in google colab?

Comment: @mohammad24 See [installing a package](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html#Installing-and-Removing-Packages) and [using packages](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Using-Packages.html). I guess it'd be something like `pkg install -forge io`, which you'd do once, and then `pkg load io`, which you'd do at the top of your script before using the `xlsread` function.

Comment: Unfortunatyl  I got   File "<ipython-input-4-9e5a85844d25>", line 1
    pkg install -forge io
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
when I used pkg install -forge io

Comment: @mohammad24 `pkg` is an Octave command, not a Python command.

Comment: you mean there is no way to install the Octave package in google colab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244039/discussion-between-mohammad24-and-cris-luengo).

Comment: @mohammad24 Maybe something like `!octave -W --eval "pkg install -forge io"` would work?